# htaccess rule for internal redirection is not working?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

http://www.example.com/class/part-time/ is the actual url.

I want to write htaccess rule for internal redirection to url:

http://www.example.com/index.php?type=class&slug=part-time

and I am using following rule-

RewriteRule ^class/([\w-]*)/$ index.php?slug=$1&type=class

But it is not working.

Comment: What's the rest of your `.htaccess` file code?

Answer (score 0):

One method would be:

```
RewriteRule ^class/([\w-]+)/$ index.php?slug=$1&type=class [L,QSA]
```

And another would be:

```
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/$ index.php?slug=$2&type=$1 [L,QSA]
```

**Notes:**
* I didn't tested it, but you should get the idea...
* The first method's url must start with the word `class`, the second one's is for dinamic urls
* Don't forget the `[L]` flag on your rules, as not using it might get unexpected results
* Don't forget the `[QSA]` flag on your rules if you are appending other `GET` values
* `$1` catches everything from `([\w-]+)` set, $2 from the second set
* I used `([\w-]+)` instead of `([\w-]*)` as that part of url is mandatory

Comment: @Praful: As I said in my answer, this is not tested. But with minor tweaks, it will work. Just test it.